# PHP pagination range

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, range

I've tried using Google and other sources but I can't find an answer. I have even looked at other's coding and still don't understand. I'm wanting to create a pagination (success) but when displaying the links, I want to be able to add a range. For example: 123...789...13 14 15 and so on. So it skips a few links until near the number.

Could someone explain how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Guys, I wonder, have you asked him to do so in the answers already? Typically this works with grateful newbies :) UPD. sorry, his problems seems more general that I've imagined at first.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this in a general way that allows a user to rapidly reach any page in the entire range, consider using "logarithmic pagination" as described in my answer here:

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)

PHP code is included, and it'll do everything your question requests.